# How to iterate through basename output via SSH

Tags: bash, ssh

I'm attempting to look through several known directories on remote machines and find the latest complete backup folder.  We can presume I start with an array of SCP-style paths, e.g `host:/path/to/dir`

```
for path in ${paths[@]}
do
  IFS=':' read host backupDir <<< "$path"

  result=`ssh "$host" 'basename $(find '"$backupDir"'/* -type d -maxdepth 1)'`

  echo "$result"
  readarray -t backups <<<"$result"
  echo "$backups"

  for backup in "$backups"
  do
    echo 1
    echo "$backup"
  done
done
```

`echo "$result"` suggests the SSH results are as expected, listing off a handful of folder names, one per line.

However, `echo $backups` only lists the first folder, and of course the inner loop similarly reflects only a single entry in the $backups array.  I've tried `readarray`, I've tried `read -a` constructs with various IFS settings, but something is eluding me about how to properly process the output from the SSH request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an array there, accessing it through `$array` gives only the first element. You should use the `${array[@]}` notation.

```
for path in ${paths[@]}
do
  IFS=':' read host backupDir <<< "$path"

  result=`ssh "$host" 'basename $(find '"$backupDir"'/* -type d -maxdepth 1)'`

  echo "$result"
  readarray -t backups <<<"$result"
  echo "${backups[@]}"

  for backup in "${backups[@]}"
  do
    echo 1
    echo "$backup"
  done
done
```